# Not a Group By expression Error

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, ora-00979

I have a `SQL` like this;

```
SELECT B.MUS_K_ISIM AS CUSTOMER_NAME, B.HESAP_NO AS CUSTOMER_NO,
    SUM(B.RISK) AS TOTAL_RISK, 
    (CASE WHEN B.DOVIZ_KOD = 21 THEN 'EUR' WHEN B.DOVIZ_KOD = 2 THEN 'USD' WHEN B.DOVIZ_KOD = 1 THEN 'TL' END) AS CCY,
    ROUND(RISK_CV(:TAR,B.HESAP_NO,B.DOVIZ_KOD),2) AS TOTAL_RISK_EUR,
    ROUND(SUM(MV_EX(B.TEKLIF_NO1,B.TEKLIF_NO2,:TAR)),2) AS RESALE_VALUE_OLD,
    ROUND(SUM(M_V(B.TEKLIF_NO1,B.TEKLIF_NO2,:TAR)),2) AS RESALE_VALUE_NEW,
    NVL(IPOTEK(B.HESAP_NO),0) AS SECURITIES,
    NVL(ROUND(GECIKME_CV(:TAR,B.HESAP_NO, 0, 30, B.DOVIZ_KOD),2),0) AS BUCKET1,
    NVL(ROUND(GECIKME_CV(:TAR,B.HESAP_NO, 30, 60, B.DOVIZ_KOD),2),0) AS BUCKET2,
    NVL(ROUND(GECIKME_CV(:TAR,B.HESAP_NO, 60, 90, B.DOVIZ_KOD),2),0) AS BUCKET3,
    NVL(ROUND(GECIKME_CV(:TAR,B.HESAP_NO, 90, 9999, B.DOVIZ_KOD),2),0) AS BUCKET4,
    (CASE WHEN GECIKME_CV(:TAR,B.HESAP_NO, 90, 9999, B.DOVIZ_KOD) > 0 THEN 100 WHEN B.HESAP_NO IN (SELECT HESAP_NO FROM S_TAKIP_MUSTERI) THEN 100 ELSE 0 END) AS PROV,
    (CASE WHEN B.HESAP_NO IN (SELECT HESAP_NO FROM S_TAKIP_MUSTERI) THEN 'E' ELSE 'H' END) AS CAT5,
    ROUND(RISK_CV(:TAR,B.HESAP_NO,B.DOVIZ_KOD)-SUM(M_V(B.TEKLIF_NO1,B.TEKLIF_NO2,:TAR))-NVL(IPOTEK(B.HESAP_NO),0),2) AS NET_PROV,
    (CASE WHEN (RISK_CV(:TAR,B.HESAP_NO,B.DOVIZ_KOD)-SUM(M_V(B.TEKLIF_NO1,B.TEKLIF_NO2,:TAR))-NVL(IPOTEK(B.HESAP_NO),0))<0 OR 
    NVL(ROUND(GECIKME_CV(:TAR,B.HESAP_NO, 90, 9999, B.DOVIZ_KOD),2),0) <= 0 THEN 0 
    ELSE ROUND((RISK_CV(:TAR,B.HESAP_NO,B.DOVIZ_KOD)-SUM(M_V(B.TEKLIF_NO1,B.TEKLIF_NO2,:TAR))-NVL(IPOTEK(B.HESAP_NO),0)),2) END) AS CORR_PROV
    FROM S_TEKLIF B
    WHERE NVL(B.RISK,0) > 0 
    --AND (GECIKME_CV(:TAR,B.HESAP_NO, 60, 90, B.DOVIZ_KOD) > 0 OR GECIKME_CV(:TAR,B.HESAP_NO, 90, 9999, B.DOVIZ_KOD) > 0) 
    GROUP BY B.MUS_K_ISIM, B.HESAP_NO, (CASE WHEN B.DOVIZ_KOD = 21 THEN 'EUR' WHEN B.DOVIZ_KOD = 2 THEN 'USD' WHEN B.DOVIZ_KOD = 1 THEN 'TL' END), ROUND(RISK_CV(:TAR,B.HESAP_NO,B.DOVIZ_KOD),2), NVL(IPOTEK(B.HESAP_NO),0), NVL(ROUND(GECIKME_CV(:TAR,B.HESAP_NO, 0, 30, B.DOVIZ_KOD),2),0), NVL(ROUND(GECIKME_CV(:TAR,B.HESAP_NO, 30, 60, B.DOVIZ_KOD),2),0), NVL(ROUND(GECIKME_CV(:TAR,B.HESAP_NO, 60, 90, B.DOVIZ_KOD),2),0), NVL(ROUND(GECIKME_CV(:TAR,B.HESAP_NO, 90, 9999, B.DOVIZ_KOD),2),0), (CASE WHEN GECIKME_CV(:TAR,B.HESAP_NO, 90, 9999, B.DOVIZ_KOD) > 0 THEN 100 WHEN B.HESAP_NO IN (SELECT HESAP_NO FROM S_TAKIP_MUSTERI) THEN 100 ELSE 0 END), (CASE WHEN B.HESAP_NO IN (SELECT HESAP_NO FROM S_TAKIP_MUSTERI) THEN 'E' ELSE 'H' END)
    ORDER BY B.MUS_K_ISIM
```

But i getting this error.

```
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

I can't put this code to `GROUP BY`?

```
(CASE WHEN GECIKME_CV(:TAR,B.HESAP_NO, 90, 9999, B.DOVIZ_KOD) > 0 THEN 100 WHEN B.HESAP_NO IN (SELECT HESAP_NO FROM S_TAKIP_MUSTERI) THEN 100 ELSE 0 END)
```

I don't understand the error!!

Comment: You should really use `WITH` clause.

Comment: @Soner Gönül: see [this link](http://psoug.org/reference/with.html) to understand what is meant here.

Comment: @Soner Gönül: Yes you can do it without WITH but can you really understand easily what this SQL statement does? I don't.

Comment: I agree with @Benoit that this is a really confusing SQL statement.  You have way too many repeated calls.  Excessive use of cut'n'paste is always a sign of underlying problems.  What I think you need to do is *rewrite your query*: use inline views to remove the repetition.

Comment: @APC But i want to add only one more WHEN clause in CASE clause.. Why is getting more complicated my query add this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a really annoying feature of the ANSI SQL statndard that any column which is not an aggregate needs to be included in the GROUP BY clause.  This is a classic piece of stupid duplication, when it's obvious (I believe MySQL allows us to ignore this part of the standard).

So, I'm afraid what it means is, you need to include the `CASE()` clause in the GROUP BY clause.

---

I think the problem is that you reference `SUM()` at two levels in the query: both at the toppermost level, `SUM(B.RISK)` but also in the calculations which provide grouping values:

```
( CASE WHEN ( RISK_CV ( :TAR , B.HESAP_NO , B.DOVIZ_KOD )
                   - SUM ( M_V ( B.TEKLIF_NO1 , B.TEKLIF_NO2 , :TAR ) )
                   - NVL ( IPOTEK ( B.HESAP_NO ) , 0 ) ) < 0
```

This is pretty tricky to get right.

I think the easiest way to resolve this is to build up the query from nested inline queries.  I have re-written your query with three levels.  The innermost query - `IQ` -  selects the data, including the functions without any aggregations.  The middle query - `SQ` - calculates the sums.  The outermost query applies rounding and other things; this should return the results as per your existing query.

```
SELECT sq.MUS_K_ISIM AS CUSTOMER_NAME, 
    sq.HESAP_NO AS CUSTOMER_NO,
    sq.TOTAL_RISK,
    (CASE WHEN sq.DOVIZ_KOD = 21 THEN 'EUR' 
        WHEN sq.DOVIZ_KOD = 2 THEN 'USD' 
        WHEN sq.DOVIZ_KOD = 1 THEN 'TL' END) AS CCY,
    ROUND(sq.RISK_EUR,2) AS TOTAL_RISK_EUR,
    ROUND(sq.RESALE_VALUE_OLD,2) AS RESALE_VALUE_OLD,
    ROUND(sq.RESALE_VALUE_OLD,2) AS RESALE_VALUE_NEW,
    sq.SECURITIES,
    NVL(ROUND(sq.BUCKET1,2),0) AS BUCKET1,
    NVL(ROUND(sq.BUCKET2,2),0) AS BUCKET2,
    NVL(ROUND(sq.BUCKET3,2),0) AS BUCKET3,
    NVL(ROUND(sq.BUCKET4,2),0) AS BUCKET4,
    (CASE WHEN sq.BUCKET4,2) > 0 THEN 100 
            WHEN sq.CAT5 = 'H' THEN 100 
            ELSE 0 END) AS PROV,
    sq.CAT5,
    sq.NET_PROV,
    (CASE WHEN sq.NET_PROV <0 
    OR
    sq.RISK_EUR <= 0 THEN 0
    ELSE ROUND(sq.NET_PROV,2) END) AS CORR_PROV
from (
    select 
            iq.MUS_K_ISIM , 
            iq.HESAP_NO ,
            iq.DOVIZ_KOD, 
            iq.RISK_EUR,
            iq.SECURITIES,
            iq.BUCKET1,
            iq.BUCKET2,
            iq.BUCKET3,
            iq.BUCKET4,
            iq.CAT5
            sum(iq.RISK) as TOTAL_RISK,
            sum(iq.RESALE_VALUE_OLD) as RESALE_VALUE_OLD,
            sum(iq.RESALE_VALUE_NEW) as RESALE_VALUE_NEW,
            iq.RISK_EUR - sum(iq.RESALE_VALUE_NEW) - iq.SECURITIES) AS NET_PROV
        from (
            SELECT B.MUS_K_ISIM , 
                   B.HESAP_NO ,
                   B.RISK,
                   B.DOVIZ_KOD, 
                   RISK_CV(:TAR,B.HESAP_NO,B.DOVIZ_KOD) AS RISK_EUR,
                   MV_EX(B.TEKLIF_NO1,B.TEKLIF_NO2,:TAR) AS RESALE_VALUE_OLD,
                   M_V(B.TEKLIF_NO1,B.TEKLIF_NO2,:TAR) AS RESALE_VALUE_NEW,
                   NVL(IPOTEK(B.HESAP_NO),0) AS SECURITIES,
                   GECIKME_CV(:TAR,B.HESAP_NO, 0, 30, B.DOVIZ_KOD) AS BUCKET1,
                   GECIKME_CV(:TAR,B.HESAP_NO, 30, 60, B.DOVIZ_KOD) AS BUCKET2,
                   GECIKME_CV(:TAR,B.HESAP_NO, 60, 90, B.DOVIZ_KOD) AS BUCKET3,
                   GECIKME_CV(:TAR,B.HESAP_NO, 90, 9999, B.DOVIZ_KOD) AS BUCKET4,
                   nvl2(M.HESAP_NO, 'E', 'H') AS CAT5
            from     
                FROM S_TEKLIF B
                    left outer join S_TAKIP_MUSTERI on (B.HESAP_NO = M.HESAP_NO)
                WHERE NVL(B.RISK,0) > 0
            ) iq        
        group by     
                iq.MUS_K_ISIM , 
                iq.HESAP_NO ,
                iq.DOVIZ_KOD, 
                iq.RISK_EUR,
                iq.SECURITIES,
                iq.BUCKET1,
                iq.BUCKET2,
                iq.BUCKET3,
                iq.BUCKET4,
                iq.CAT5
        )sq
ORDER BY sq.MUS_K_ISIM
/
```

Obviously, this may not compile - I haven't got your database schema to check against. Also the logic may be wrong; I have had to make assumptions about your business logic.  However, I do think this is easier to understand and will be easier to get debug.

Comment: I already put my GROUP BY clause this (CASE WHEN GECIKME_CV(:TAR,B.HESAP_NO, 90, 9999, B.DOVIZ_KOD) > 0 THEN 100 WHEN B.HESAP_NO IN (SELECT HESAP_NO FROM S_TAKIP_MUSTERI) THEN 100 ELSE 0 END) code.. What i doing wrong??

Answer (score 2):

```
 , ROUND ( RISK_CV ( :TAR , B.HESAP_NO , B.DOVIZ_KOD )
         - SUM ( M_V ( B.TEKLIF_NO1 , B.TEKLIF_NO2 , :TAR ) )
  - NVL ( IPOTEK ( B.HESAP_NO ) , 0 ) , 2 )
```

This is not an aggregate function. Only the SUM part is there. Use [Analytic functions](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0320__Analytical-Functions/PARTITIONBYclausedividesthegroupsintosubgroups.htm).

Comment: My top SQL is working good, Just an error with (CASE WHEN GECIKME_CV(:TAR,B.HESAP_NO, 90, 9999, B.DOVIZ_KOD) > 0 THEN 100 WHEN B.HESAP_NO IN (SELECT HESAP_NO FROM S_TAKIP_MUSTERI) THEN 100 ELSE 0 END) in GROUP BY clause..

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you might want to post a complete example next time - when trying to run your query, I get errors for at least 4 undefined functions and 2 not existing tables (S_TEKLIF, GECIKME_CV, ipotek, risk_cv, m_v, mv_ex - I gave up after that).

Second: try to split this up into two queries, something like

```
select mus_k_isim, hesap_no, my_key, ... from 
(select mus_k_isim, b.hesap_no, 
  (CASE WHEN B.DOVIZ_KOD = 21 THEN 'EUR' WHEN B.DOVIZ_KOD = 2 THEN 'USD' WHEN B.DOVIZ_KOD = 1 THEN 'TL' END), ROUND(RISK_CV(:TAR,B.HESAP_NO,B.DOVIZ_KOD),2), NVL(IPOTEK(B.HESAP_NO),0), NVL(ROUND(GECIKME_CV(:TAR,B.HESAP_NO, 0, 30, B.DOVIZ_KOD),2),0), NVL(ROUND(GECIKME_CV(:TAR,B.HESAP_NO, 30, 60, B.DOVIZ_KOD),2),0), NVL(ROUND(GECIKME_CV(:TAR,B.HESAP_NO, 60, 90, B.DOVIZ_KOD),2),0), NVL(ROUND(GECIKME_CV(:TAR,B.HESAP_NO, 90, 9999, B.DOVIZ_KOD),2),0), (CASE WHEN GECIKME_CV(:TAR,B.HESAP_NO, 90, 9999, B.DOVIZ_KOD) > 0 THEN 100 WHEN B.HESAP_NO IN (SELECT HESAP_NO FROM S_TAKIP_MUSTERI) THEN 100 ELSE 0 END), (CASE WHEN B.HESAP_NO IN (SELECT HESAP_NO FROM S_TAKIP_MUSTERI) THEN 'E' ELSE 'H' END) my_key
from ...
) group by mus_k_isim, hesap_no, my_key
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `case` references a select statement - and you can't have a select statement in a group by clause.

Comment: Do i have yo select statement in my GROUP BY clause? And why?

Comment: You're grouping the results and one of your group by clauses has the case statement which is fine - except that the case statement includes the select which is not fine

Comment: my one column (CASE WHEN GECIKME_CV(:TAR,B.HESAP_NO, 90, 9999, B.DOVIZ_KOD) > 0 THEN 100 WHEN B.HESAP_NO IN (SELECT HESAP_NO FROM S_TAKIP_MUSTERI) THEN 100 ELSE 0 END) AS PROV and also i add this my group by (CASE WHEN GECIKME_CV(:TAR,B.HESAP_NO, 90, 9999, B.DOVIZ_KOD) > 0 THEN 100 WHEN B.HESAP_NO IN (SELECT HESAP_NO FROM S_TAKIP_MUSTERI) THEN 100 ELSE 0 END) But this doesn't work. I kill myself..

Comment: To reiterate - you cannot have a Select statement in a group by clause. Consider moving the case logic to a function and replace the case references to the function in group by.